# Memory leak while using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image,nil, nil, nil);?

Tags: iphone

Memory leak while using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image,nil, nil, nil);?
how can i remove memory leak for this situation?
when i try with out this line,There is no memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

The nil,nil,nil is your problem.

One of those nils, is called (SEL)completionSelector

You pass it a method selector.  Inside that method, you free the memory.  Apple's documentation explains this if I recall correctly.  If not, I'm sure I've seen something by searching google showing how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the Simulator may leak memory when the device does not.

Always test on the device for leaks.

Good luck!